# The beamer presentation is very small

Tags: beamer

My presentation create with `beamer` is very small. Exist any to enlarge horizontally?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{PaloAlto}

%\setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title[Managerial Economics]{VW Invasion of North America} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\institute[FDSM] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{
\textit{Fudan Business} \\\textit{School of Management} \\ % Your institution for the title page
\medskip
%\textit{bofu20131@163.com} % Your email address
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date


\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section 1}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want the black parts of the pages (see image) to disappear, how can I make the leaves grow horizontally?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. The code you provided contains the side bar and top bar with title frame.

Comment: @Sigur I want the black parts of the pages to disappear, how can I make the leaves grow horizontally?

Comment: So, I think you want another size for pdf. Try `\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}` to use aspect ratio 16x9. See *8.3 Frame and Margin Sizes* from Beamer user guide for more ratios.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are viewing a pdf in widescreen so some black strip appear on both sides if the pdf has not the same ratio.

You can change the ratio with

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
```

or, from the user guide, *Section 8.3 Frame and Margin Sizes* a lot of other ratios.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your document doesn't include the black parts--those are from your pdf viewer software (acrobat?).

By default beamer creates pages that are 5.04in x 3.78in. Your pdf viewer will usually expand that to fill the screen. Since the aspect ratio of your file (4:3) doesn't match the aspect ratio of your screen, your pdf viewer is displaying black to the right and left.